# Ways to introduce a name in the middle of sentence

Tags: grammar, names, sentence-patterns

Suppose that you want to introduce a name of a thing or count several names  of things in a sentence (e.g. they are namely "X", "Y", "Z")

For example I know "called", "namely", perhaps "named" are used for this purpose.

What are the common ways to do this? What is the related grammar and structure?

For example:

> By specifying these tags, now we can create a node, named “product”, which is ...

Is this correct?

Comment: This is an information-adding parenthetical.

Comment: What you suggest is correct.  It has nothing to do with English grammar, though -- the introduced name is just text.  You could have said "... create a node, colored red, which is ..." and the grammar would be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no different grammar specifically for the verb 'naming', which is what you seem to be asking. As Edwin commented, it could be a parenthesis between two commas, in which case you would be well-advised to omit the comma after *tags* and could if you wished omit *named*. It could be a noun phrase, *a node named 'product'*. Or you could start your sentence with the name: *'Product', the new node we have created...*

The important thing is to work out what you intend, and make that clear to the reader. For example, I have no idea what "mention/count" is intended to signify; counting requires numbers rather than grammar, and *mention* in this context would refer to the difference between 'product' as a mathematical term and 'Product' as a name.  From the rest of the sentence, I infer that you intend something like 'introduce'; if I am wrong, you should edit your question rather than trying to explain in comments.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't get what you mean completely, but I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

#### Here are some examples of mentioning name in a sentence:

> ##### named

- A man named John answered the door.
- They named their son John.
- John was named after his grandfather.
- He was named as the executor of the will.

> ##### namely

- We studied the cat family, namely, lions, tigers, and related animals.
- It was another color, namely red.
- He suggested that these so-called contributions are something else, namely taxes.

> ##### Called

- They've called the twins Robert and Julienne.
- His real name is Donald, but they've always called him Don.
- I wish he wouldn't keep calling me "honey" - it's so patronizing!
- He was called as chief witness.

> ##### i.e.

- The basic essentials of life, i.e. housing, food and water.
- The hotel is closed during the low season, i.e. from October to March.
- The price must be more realistic, i.e. lower.